# QTextEdit does not apply css to html table

Tags: python, html, css, pyqt, markdown

I am using QTextEdit to display some markdown content. I am using QT version 5 and cannot move to 6 to use [`QTextEdit.setMarkdown`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTextEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTextEdit.setMarkdown). For achieving this, I convert the markdown to html and then display the html usnig the QTextEdit as showin in this example:

```py
from markdown import markdown
from markdown.extensions.tables import TableExtension

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Application
    app = QApplication([])

    # Display markdown
    text_edit = QTextEdit()
    text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
    text_edit.setMinimumSize(QSize(800,600))
    style = """
            table {
                border: 5px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            h1 {
              background-color: black;
              color: white;
            }
            h2 {
              background-color: yellow;
              color: red;
            }
            """
    text_edit.document().setDefaultStyleSheet(style)

    # Markdown
    markdown_text= "# My markdown\n" \
                   "## My subheader\n" \
                   "\n" \
                   "this is the text followed by bullets\n" \
                   "\n" \
                   "- Point 1\n" \
                   "- Point 2\n" \
                   "- Point 3\n" \
                   "\n" \
                   "And now a table:\n\n" \
                   "|Col 1|Col 2|Col 3|\n" \
                   "|---|---|---|\n" \
                   "|Col 1 content|Col 2 content|Col 3 content|\n" \
                   "|Col 1 content 2|Col2 content 2|Col 3 content 2|\n"
    html_text = markdown(markdown_text, extensions=[TableExtension(use_align_attribute=True)])
    text_edit.setHtml(html_text)

    # Show
    text_edit.show()
    app.exec()
```

Which produces:
[image]

As you can appreciate, I can add a CSS style to the document (h1 and h2) in the QTextEdit. However, the table part of the CSS is not being applied (there is no border). According to [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) the table properties that I am using are supported. Any idea on what can I do to apply the table style?

Comment: You must set the border on the `<table>` tag too, setting it in the stylesheet is not sufficient. Also, [`setMarkDown()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#markdown-prop) was available before Qt6, since Qt 5.14.